# notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh ListView after removing an item in getItemView()

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have an adapter which extends `ParseQueryAdapter`. I want to remove an item within the function `getItemView()`, so I call:

```
public View getItemView(final AlertObject alertObject, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

... // Some conditions
    alertObject.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e == null) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                LogUtils.e(LogUtils.getTag(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
...

}
```

However the `ListView` does not refresh after removing the item. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The mapping between Adapter and ListView is done as in the following:

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AlertObject> factory =
        new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AlertObject>() {
            public ParseQuery<AlertObject> create() {
                ParseQuery<AlertObject> query = AlertObject.getQuery();
                query.orderByDescending(AlertObject.TIMESTAMP_KEY);
                query.fromLocalDatastore();
                return query;
            }
        };

alertsListAdapter = new AlertListItemAdapter(activity, factory);
alertsListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.alerts_list_view);
alertsListView.setAdapter(alertsListAdapter);
```

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

At the moment I'm using an alternative solution, that is refreshing the fragment after deletion:

```
((MainActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .detach(listAlertsFragment)
    .attach(listAlertsFragment)
    .commit();
```

Comment: How are you storing the items in your listview?

Comment: share other information also just your adapter is custom, dataset used for that

Comment: I've edited my question, please see the update, thank you! :)

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are deleting the object on the remote server, but not actually removing it from the list that is displayed locally. This also seems like a weird place to be doing this operation - why are you removing rows when you are trying to display them? I think you need to re approach this as that method should only be returning views

Comment: @AndrewBreen: because I have a trash button (an ``ImageView``) for each item in the ListView (and I build the item view in the adapter), so when the button is pressed that item must be deleted. However, maybe you're right... the item is removed from a remote server, but not locally. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: If you have a button to remove them, you can have a onclicklistener for each row that is responsible for removing that row. Otherwise this current code is only doing the deletion when its trying to display that row again.

Comment: Yes, I have ``OnClickListener`` defined within the ``getItemView`` method... Is this approach wrong? However, when I click on the button of an item, the record is deleted (I know that because the ``deleteInBackground`` callback successes), but the view is not updated. I've also tried to change ``deleteInBackground`` with ``unpinInBackground``, which removes the element from the local datastore, but nothing changed.